# How do I get php to echo value outside of loop?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I want to be able to put the name of the person in the email.  But I don't know how to retain the value outside the loop.  Also, I'm wondering if this will work if there is more than one result.

Here is the php:

```
// WHO HAS BEEN A MEMBER FOR ONE YEAR
function joinDateFilter(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
    $mail_to = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['name']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
        $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
        $name = $row['name'];
    }
    if (!empty($mail_to)){
        sendEmail($mail_to);
    }
}

// SEND EMAIL
function sendEmail($mail_to) {
    $from    = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
    $message = "Happy Anniversary!";
    $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($mail_to, "Congratulations ".$name."!", $message, $headers);
}
```

In that example above, the mail never reads their name, as the value seems to be forgotten outside of the while loop.  Can someone help me?

Comment: You should send the email inside the loop. Otherwise, you're just sending mail to the last person found by the query.

Comment: Did you intend to concatenate all the emails into one long `$mail_to` list? You're not doing that, you're overwriting the variable each time through the loop.

Comment: I recommend you to use [PHP-Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial). This would be way easyer for you to send mails. Btw, why you want to echo anyways ?

Comment: Make $name global `global $name;`

Comment: and please DONT use globals ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your code overwrites the email id stored in `$mail_to` in each iteration of the `while` loop. So, it will have only the email id of the last user. And you need name of each user (stored in `$name` and used in the function). You need to send the email whenever a user is found. Try this:

```
// WHO HAS BEEN A MEMBER FOR ONE YEAR
function joinDateFilter(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['name']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
        $mail_to = $row['email'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        if (!empty($mail_to))
            sendEmail($mail_to, $name);
    }
}

// SEND EMAIL
function sendEmail($mail_to, $name) {
    $from    = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
    $message = "Happy Anniversary!";
    $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($mail_to, "Congratulations ".$name."!", $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to put the send mail function inside the loop and add a name parameter in the function since you are using it inside the function.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
// WHO HAS BEEN A MEMBER FOR ONE YEAR
function joinDateFilter(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
    $mail_to = "";
    $name = "";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['name']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
        $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
        $name = $row['name'];
      if (!empty($mail_to) and !empty($name)){
        sendEmail($mail_to, $name);
      }
   }
}

// SEND EMAIL
function sendEmail($mail_to, $name) {
    $from    = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
    $message = "Happy Anniversary!";
    $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($mail_to, "Congratulations ".$name."!", $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), you could do some like:

```
function joinDateFilter(){

    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail           = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From     = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
    $mail->Subject  = "Congratulations";
    $mail->Body     = "Happy Anniversary!";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $mail->AddBCC($row['email'],$row['name']);
    }
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
}
```

Or if you want to have diffrent Subjects than you could do this...

```
function joinDateFilter(){

    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail           = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From     = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
    $mail->Body     = "Happy Anniversary!";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $mail->Subject  = "Congratulations " . $row['name'];
        $mail->AddAddress($row['email'],$row['name']);
        $mail->Send();
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
    }
}
```

Anyway, you save 1 function and its kind of handy to :D

And its also very easy to add attachments or sending html emails and stuff like this. How to do most things can be googled. So you may need a small [tutorial](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial).

If you download the mailer pac, you really only need the `class.phpmailer.php` the rest is not necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php

    // WHO HAS BEEN A MEMBER FOR ONE YEAR
    function joinDateFilter(){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE date_joined = DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)");
        $mail_to = "";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo $row['name']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
            $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
            $name = $row['name'];
            if (!empty($mail_to)){
                sendEmail($mail_to, $name);
            }
        }

    }

    // SEND EMAIL
    function sendEmail($mail_to, $name) {
        $from    = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
        $message = "Happy Anniversary!";
        $headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($mail_to, "Congratulations ".$name."!", $message, $headers);
    }

?>
```

Keep in mind that mail function can be sometimes problematic. Google about that issue. What you can use as an replacement for the mail function is [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)